# request.getParameter is always fetching null

Tags: jsp

```
I have the following code in a .jsp file:
 <select name="Nsem" id = "Nsem">
            <option value="1">First</option>
            <option value="2" selected>Second</option>
            <option value="3">Third</option>
 </select>
 <%
         out.println("</br><p> The selected semester is"+request.getParameter("Nsem"));
  %>
```

but this is fetching `null` and not option values.

Comment: What is the purpose of getting the dropdown value? If you want to send it to servlet, You would've use Javascript and Ajax.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
            function disp()
            {
                var s =document.getElementById("Nsem");
                selVal = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
                document.write("The selected semester is"+selVal);
            }
            </script>                                                                                      If I use javascript then this value(selVal) gets printed in another page. I want the value to be printed in the same page where I have my drop down.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vinzykrish/rfuvh3nL/2/).

Javascript,

```
<script>  
    window.displayValue = function() { 
         var e = document.getElementById("Nsem");
         var selVal = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value; 
         var span = document.getElementById("selectedValue");
         span.innerHTML = selVal;   //This will add value like 1/2/3
    }
</script>
```

In Your HTML add a span tag,

```
<select name="Nsem" id = "Nsem" onchange="disp();">
   <option value="1">First</option>
   <option value="2" selected>Second</option>
   <option value="3">Third</option>
</select>
<span id="selectedValue"></span>
```

Hope this helps.